# Rewriting an if statement to make it more condensed and cleaner

Tags: c++

I am working on a school assignment. What I want to do is not the focus of the assignment, merely something I would like to do better.

I have the following if statement where equation is a string

```
if( (equation[0]== "*") || (equation[0]== "/") || (equation[0]== "+") || (equation[0]== "-"))
```

All it does is check to see if the first and last characters of the string are one of 4 operators. This is long, bulky, and hopefully not the best way of doing this. Sadly I do not have access to regular expressions as this type of check would be very easy using them.

Is there a better way of writing the if statement without using regular expressions? Something along the lines of

```
if( equation[0] == ("/" || "*" || "+" || "-"))
```

Comment: No, there's no other way. If you have lots of similar `if` statements all after each other then you might change to a `switch` statement instead (though it will not work with strings, checking characters will work fine).

Comment: If `equation` is a `string`, then `equation[0]` is a `char`.

Comment: As everyone said, it's not possible. However, for future reference the [Ternary Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) in a sense condenses `if` statements.

Comment: Your existing `if` expression won't work: `equation[0]` will evaluate to a `char` value, but double-quoted values are strings, so the `==` operator will be comparing a character value to a memory address, which is nonsensical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
if(std::string("*/+-").find(equation[0])!=std::string::npos)
```

Comment: (I should add that I haven't written C++ in over five years but I think the syntax is correct...)

Comment: This is good, but it has a run time of `O(n)` and the original `if` statement technically has `O(1)` not really a problem in this case but could potentially be a problem if used in a different example.

Comment: I would not say that this is "cleaner". It's definitely not more readable or clearer. A comment in the code explaining this would be mandatory IMO.

Comment: @GaryJohnson original if statement is not O(1) because each statement will be checked one by one, so it'll be same O(N), but with little less memory

Comment: @DenisSheremet in this example that may be true. As I stated that it's not a problem. However, a different example could potentially cause a problem. Just something to be aware of

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using `switch` operator

```
switch(equation[0]) {
  case '/':
  case '*':
  case '+':
  case '-':
    //your code
    break;
  default:
    //else statement
}
```

Comment: If doing this with c++17 (if anyone is yet) then they should consider using the [`[[fallthrough]]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to do what you're asking.

Best you can do is put `equation[0]` in another shorter name variable.

```
std::string a = equation[0];

if( (a"*") || (a== "/") || (a== "+") || (a== "-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. But I think it's always cleaner and more readable to

```
switch (equation[0]) {
case '*':
case '/':
case '+':
case '-':
    //dostuff
    break;
default:
    //dostuff
}
```

This way, it's also really easy to replace (add or remove) new characters. If you would to it with a regular expression, that would be definetely more work to do.